# UIStackView appearing differently in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, xib

I have a simple test `UIStackView` which shows different results on iOS and Interface builder.

This is how the `UIStackView` looks like on iOS:

[image]

The same UIStackView in Interface Builder:

[image]

How is it possible that in Interface Builder there are different visual results than during runtime?

Some of the differences are:

1. There's some top spacing above the red square.
2. The outline of the selected blue square appears above the square in IB instead of around it.

Answer (score 0):

I also facing the same issue sometimes.

This might be Xcode interface builder issue. so you should do following steps.

1. close storyboard and open again.
2. close Xcode and open again.

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out simulated metrics are responsible for this problem. I use XIB's to create my UI and I used a simulated top bar since this is included in the screen. Removing this simulated metric **top bar** fixed the issue:

[image]